# What is this function, utilising stripslashes(), actually doing?

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to learn Object-Orientated PHP using the `mysqli_*` extension via [this tutorial](http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/using-object-oriented-php-with-the-mysqli-extension/).

It seems a little dated, as they have in their connection file a reference to `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` which has been removed from PHP, correct?

There is a function on the page that reads as so:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function sanitize($value) {
        $value = is_array($value) ?
        array_map('sanitize', $value) :
        stripslashes($value);
        return $value;
    }
    $_POST = array_map('sanitize', $_POST);
    $_GET = array_map('sanitize', $_POST);
    $_COOKIE = array_map('sanitize', $_COOKIE);
    $_REQUEST = array_map('sanitize', $_REQUEST);
}
```

Now, if I **took the code out** of the initial `if` statement, 1) would it work, and 2) is it needed? I'm not quite sure what it does.

The most I can deduce is that it runs a `stripslashes()` on every value in a `$_POST`, `$_GET`, etc. array and returns them back sanitized. Is this correct? If it only used to run when Magic Quotes was turned on, and now it's been removed, does it even have a valid use now?

Comment: Will I need to run any sanitization on my `$_POST` and `$_GET` data later on in my code in that case, then? Or will OOP's statement format be enough? What exactly did Magic Quotes use to do to data, too? Add unnecessary backslashes?

Comment: Since superglobals can contain arrays of arrays of arrays ... of arrays (you get the idea), that code simply traverses the array(s) and if value is an array again - it traverses it recursively until every array value is stripslashes-d.

Comment: @mpdc — You need to sanitize data when you use it somewhere subject to code execution (SQL, HTML, JavaScript, etc) how you do that depends on where you use it. Magic Quotes were an ineffective attempt to sanitize data for SQL automatically. Stripslashes undoes it. There are probably valid uses for stripslashes, but they are obscure.

Comment: Once upon a time, it was used for removing the slashes added by magic_quotes_gpc, usually called `stripslashes_deep`

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, this has really made things understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be re-written like this if it helps:

```
function sanitize($value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        $value = array_map('sanitize', $value);
    } else {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }

    return $value;
}
```

If `$value` is an array it's running itself on each item and if it's a string it's just running `stripslashes` it. Take a look at the documentation on [php.net](http://php.net) [`stripslashes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)  [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for more information. It'll basically take either a string or an array and run `stripslashes` on each value.

Check out the [ternary](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) operator too to help clear up the strange looking `if` statement.

Comment: A nice and simple explanation of rewriting the ternary. Thank you. I had seen them before in jQuery, but never truly understood them.